# Emerge on Gentoo fails with "Multiple package instances within a single package slot have been pulled … in". How can I resolve this?

Tags: software-installation, gentoo, emerge

I'm trying to install Google Chrome on my recent Gentoo box. But `emerge` is throwing some [errors](http://pastebin.com/HMvw30Ma) that are way over my head. I genuinely don't know what the problem even is.

```
!!! Multiple package instances within a single package slot have been pulled
!!! into the dependency graph, resulting in a slot conflict:

dev-libs/glib:2

  (dev-libs/glib-2.32.4-r1::gentoo, installed) pulled in by
    <dev-libs/glib-2.33:2 required by (dev-libs/gobject-introspection-1.32.1::gentoo, installed)

  (dev-libs/glib-2.36.4-r1::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) pulled in by
    >=dev-libs/glib-2.34.0:2 required by (x11-libs/gdk-pixbuf-2.28.2::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge)
    (and 2 more with the same problem)

media-libs/fontconfig:1.0

  (media-libs/fontconfig-2.8.0-r1::gentoo, installed) pulled in by
    (no parents that aren't satisfied by other packages in this slot)

  (media-libs/fontconfig-2.10.92::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) pulled in by
    >=media-libs/fontconfig-2.10.91:1.0= required by (x11-libs/pango-1.34.1::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge)
```

I've already tried the `--backtrack=30` and `--autounmask-write` options as suggested in the output, but there is no difference in the output.

I just need to know what the problem is in order to go about finding a solution to it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error messages.

Comment: Maybe your setup is somewhat in "flux" because of some USE flag changes?... if the output suggested --autounmask-write, did you follow with [`dispatch-conf`](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=3&chap=4) to update your config? Before you tried building Chrome, did you have any problem doing `emerge --update --deep --with-bdeps=y --newuse @world` with the `emerge --depclean` and `revdep-rebuild` [commands](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=2&chap=1)?

Comment: @illuminÉ Thanks for the response. Indeed I had not updated and that was the issue. The emerge, after 2 days of updates, and headaches in between, solved the problem.

Comment: What about if the multiple instances issus is produced precisely by a `emerge --update --deep --with-bdeps=y --newuse @world`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was due to a system which was outdated. So updating it solved the issue:
        `emerge --update --deep --with-bdeps=y --newuse @world`

Comment: @Gherardo wonders "What about if the multiple instances issues is produced precisely by a `emerge --update --deep --with-bdeps=y --newuse @world`?

Comment: @drs He could make a new Q and detail the issue so that anyone could contribute.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Gentoo wiki page on troubleshooting](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Troubleshooting#Dependency_graph_slot_conflicts),
most of such cases can be resolved by emerging the latest package with, say,

```
emerge --ask --oneshot package-name
```

Comment: ...the latest package in a conflicting set. My understanding is that you would have to do that for both _glib_ and _fontconfig_ here. I may be wrong; I cannot reproduce. +1